How to Avoid WinUI ScrollView/ScrollViewer Stretching Columns
I have a WinUI 3 Page contained within a wide SplitView Pane. At a certain point of narrowing the overall application window, part of the pane is hidden, so I added a ScrollView for scrolling horizontally.
Once I did that, the content of the Grid columns (not shown and represented by an ellipses), which are set to HorizontalOrientation="Stretch" suddenly become exceedingly wide, including the content item in the column that has a width set to Width="200". Having that first column growing to, probably, a width of 600-800 was a little weird to me, but that's what it's doing.
I tried to solve this over-stretching issue by setting the ScrollView width to basically match that of the SplitView Pane because I only want to use the scroll feature if the overall app window shrinks enough to hide a portion of the pane. Setting the width did not have any effect, however.
Is there a way to set the ScrollView so that the scroller only shows when the Page is partially hidden and also doesn't stretch out the page's column's content?
Hope that's clear. Let me know if you need me to include the XAML for the column content.
                    <ScrollView
                        Width="792"
                        MaxWidth="792"
                        ContentOrientation="Horizontal">
                        <Grid>
                           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                 <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                                 <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           ...
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollView>


Might be better to help with reproducible XAML code that includes the SplitView.

Could you please provide a minimal code snippet to reproduce? Optionally a video to describe the issue.
